# How to copy 2GB video from Samsung Galaxy Orbit running Android 9 to Windows 10?

Tags: file-transfer

I recorded a nearly 2GB video of my kid at an event. Now I'm unable to transfer it to Windows 10:

- I can email pictures from my phone via gmail, but it won't do it with the large file.
- When I connect the phone to the computer with a USB cable, I don't see the phone as a drive.
- I tried the Microsoft's "Your Phone Companion", but they won't connect.
- I found something about uploading the file to Google Drive, but several hours later it still says "preparing to upload file".

Apparently there's something called "MTP" which if enabled would allow a sort of managed file transfer. But all the steps I've seen for enabling it lead to dead ends on my Samsung Galaxy Orbit running Android 9.0; if it's there, maybe it requires different steps to enable it than I've seen.

Any suggestions??

Comment: Try different USB cables. Some are made for charging only and will not allow data transfers.

Comment: @kicken Thanks, I tried another cable. But with both cables, I can see my Kindle paperwhite as a drive but cannot see this phone as a drive. Somewhere along the way I read that recent versions of Android (or was it recent Android devices?) don't allow being seen as a drive because people were doing stupid things and bricking their devices.

Comment: have you tried [airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid)

Comment: Do you have an sd card reader in your phone? And in your windows 10 machine? It would be easy to use an sd card for such transfers or maybe a usb which can be connected to the phone by an OTG cable.

Comment: @GregLovern, check if your device provides different options after being plugged in.  Mine always defaults to charging but the mode can be changed to `File Transfer` via an option in the notification area, at which point it shows as a device on the computer.

Comment: Files successfully transferred with SD card. Thanks all!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Files successfully transferred with SD card.

Comment: It's good that you could buy as an answer it's of no use to anybody because it doesn't explain *how*. Please add that the answer and feel free to accept it